# Is there any way to conver byte* message to LPCWSTR other than WideCharToMultiBYte()?

Tags: windows-ce

Is there any way to conver byte* message to LPCWSTR other than WideCharToMultiBYte()?
Thanks Reply

Abhineet Agarwal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well i got the solution for it.

If you want to convert BYTE* to LPCWSTR other than using WideCharToMultiByte then we can use in the following way:

```
//Suppose 
BYTE * message;
//where message="MessageRequest"

//now create one variable called "msg"....
WCHAR msg[100];
//Copy "message" content into "msg" .

//Now take variable of LPCWSTR type
LPCWSTR msg1;
msg1=(LPCWSTR)msg;

//and display it using DrawText(...); 
//And u will be able to see proper message.
```

Comment: This answer makes somewhere around zero sense.  Nowhere in the code does the original data in `message` get transferred into the `msg` buffer.

Answer (score 2):

With `byte*` I assume you mean a `char*` string.
If that it is true, you can use `swprintf` with the `%hs` flag.

Example:

```
wchar_t msg[100];
swprintf(msg, L"%hs", "message");
```

Answer (score 0):

[wcstombs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861432.aspx)?

Here's the example from the MSDN link:

```
void main( void )
{
   int      i;
   char    *pmbbuf   = (char *)malloc( MB_CUR_MAX );
   wchar_t *pwchello = L"Hello, world.";

   printf( "Convert wide-character string:\n" );
   i = wcstombs( pmbbuf, pwchello, MB_CUR_MAX );
   printf( "\tCharacters converted: %u\n", i );
   printf( "\tMultibyte character: %s\n\n", pmbbuf );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mbstowcs if the encoding is the default one. Otherwise, you can use iconv from libiconv or use the Windows API function, it is very easy to use, just takes several lines of code.